# Run program2 after running program1

Tags: c++, makefile, automation

I have two C++ programs namely runner.cpp and TSP.cpp, what i want is to run runner.cpp and then to have TSP.cpp run automatically after runner.cpp has finished executing. Is there a way of achieving this? If so please give detailed explanation. I think this can be done using makefile, but i don't know how to use makefile properly, so would appreciate detailed explanation. Thanks in advance. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `./runner; ./TSP`?

Comment: I don't want them running concurrently, TSP should run after runner has finished executing.

Comment: @immibis's solution runs one program at a time.

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes they do. Thanks for the help @immibis.